# set dropdown values using datetime string

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a string like this - `2019-10-21 14:54:00`

And five dropdown elements (for years, months, days, hours and minutes) like this:

```
<select id='selMonth'>
<option>01</option>
<option>02</option>
...
</select>
```

Now I need to place values from the string inside the corresponding elements, like this:

```
$('#selMonth').val(month-from-string);
$('#selHour').val(hour-from-string);
```

I tried to split the string, firstly by `space`, then first part by `-` and  the second part by `:` but I hope there is a more natural way.

Any help?

Comment: The date format from your string is already in a format javascript will understand:

    var date = new Date('2019-10-21 14:54:00');

    console.log(date.getMonth());
    console.log(date.getDate());...

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé - tried and getting `NaN` in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the date into individual values using a regular expression:

```js
const d = '2019-10-21 14:54:00';
const [, years, month, days, hours, minutes, seconds] = d.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);

console.log(years, month, days, hours, minutes, seconds)
```